# How to get current date with time and setting it to a editbox in android?

Tags: android, datetime

> How to get current date with time in android and how can we set that
>   date andtime to a editbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current date and time using:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now simply show this in your editbox like:

```
editBox.setText(String.format("%1$te %1$tB %1$tY %1$r",cal));
```

This will give you date and time like- 12 January 2009 10:34:50 pm

For displaying other date and time formats,please refer to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html